# Uploading files in a loop

Tags: python

I have a program that works when my variables are keyed in directly from the script, but I want to upload them now from a csv file.

I am used to using loops, and thought I'd upload my file names and other key data in a csv file, but my for loop falls over and generates an error:

```py
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

It works fine when I have path: `path="ms_1030_00252.dat"` as a line in the code, but if I type this as `ms_1030_00252.dat` in a csv cell, and upload, I get the error.

The path name is being changed slightly to `b'ms_1030_00252.dat'`.

The relevant part of the program is

```
for index in range(len(eccentricity)):
    path=model_path[index]
    print(path)
    data_upload=np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=None, skip_header=6)
```

I tried replacing the `b` with `replace()` and got

```py
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
```

How do I get round this?

Thank you.

Comment: Strange, the error complains about the attribute `.split`, but I don't see that anywhere in your code. Can you provide the entire stack trace? That's everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` down to the error message.

Comment: use `path.decode()`

Comment: the `b` in `b'ms_1030_00252.dat'` is not a part of the string itself. It's part of the representation and here it tells us that you don't have a string, but a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and SmartManoj.

I added a line path=path.decode('utf-8'), and everything works as it should.  Very grateful.